# Call onClick when unchecked set programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I need to reset when the user hits the browsers back-button. I have multiple checkboxes, each have a onClick-event. These looks something like this, but the onClickevent isn't the same on every box:

```
<input onclick="GetSelectedAmount();" class="PaymentType" valueid="242" type="checkbox" value="175.00">
```

I'm trying to unselect these in either `PageShow` or `window.Unload`:

```
('#aspnetForm').submit(function() {
   $(window).unload(function() {
        $('#aspnetForm').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
      });
   });
});
```

This indeed removes the checked attribute, but the onClick-event on each checkbox isn't fired. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: where is onClick event?

Comment: How about onchange instead of onclick?

Comment: I've tried Onchange - still isn't called. C-link what do you mean about where the onClick event is?

Comment: did you try `.prop("checked", false);` instead of `removeAttr`

Comment: HI SajithNair. Yes, I tried updating my jQuery library but didn't help either. Using the "Trigger" instead of removeAttr seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the attribute - try triggering click event. This can be achieved something like:-

```
$('#aspnetForm').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').trigger('click');
```

Comment: This seems to work! I implemented the following: form.find(':input').not(':button,:submit,:reset,:hidden').trigger('onclick');

Comment: In your example click event will fire irrespective of the fact whether it was previously checked or not. In my example it will only fire when it is checked... Depends on the requirement :-)